# Convert utc string to date SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a column sample_date in form of string as `200912301111230000000000` (UTC Time).How can I convert it from string to datetime in form of yyyymmdd using SQL select statement?

Comment: Fix your schema and don't store date/time values as stings but use appropriate [date/time types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html). And then you can use [`date_format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) on it or even better leave it up to the front end on how to represent the values.

Comment: I cannot change the schema since it is stored in form of delta table.

Comment: Aren't the first 8 characters of the string the date you are looking for?

Comment: @ shadow yes how to get in date format using sql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you only want yyyymmdd, which is the first 8 chacters of your string, it is enough to simply use `LEFT`

I added the ST_TO_DATE so that you can see hw a conversionto a Date column could work

> ```
> SELECT LEFT('200912301111230000000000',8),STR_TO_DATE(LEFT('200912301111230000000000',8),'%Y%m%d')
> ```
>
> ```
> LEFT('200912301111230000000000',8) | STR_TO_DATE(LEFT('200912301111230000000000',8),'%Y%m%d')
> :--------------------------------- | :-------------------------------------------------------
> 20091230                           | 2009-12-30
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dea505b1fc6cd94fc48ed6ecd64fc8c7)*

So it would loke like this

```
SELECT LEFT(Your_Column,8) FROM Your_Table
```

Comment: I've one more question.In database,I've like millions of rows.How do I apply it to the whole column ?

Comment: You replace '200912301111230000000000' with your column name... for example: `SELECT LEFT(sample_date ,8)`